# Trace and Watch (wt) on breakpoint in WinDbg

Tags: windbg

I'd like to get a trace of function calls inside comctl32.dll beginning when the left mouse button is pressed on a tree control item and while the mouse button is held down.

I can set a breakpoint on `comctl32!TV_ButtonDown` and then use `wt` when the breakpoint is hit but this requires me to release the mouse button and interact with WinDbg. When I try to use a command string for my breakpoint like this: `bp comctl32!TV_ButtonDown "wt -m comctl32"`, the tracing stops immediately after starting upon hitting the breakpoint:

```
Tracing COMCTL32!TV_ButtonDown to return address 00007ffd`57a48f1d

0 instructions were executed in 0 events (0 from other threads)

Function Name                               Invocations MinInst MaxInst AvgInst

0 system calls were executed

COMCTL32!TV_ButtonDown+0x5:
00007ffd`57b03bd9 48896c2418      mov     qword ptr [rsp+18h],rbp ss:000000b7`746f8b00=0000000000000201
```

Is what I am attempting possible? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @ThomasWeller TV_ButtonDown calls TV_CheckForDragBegin which pumps messages. When I have to interact with windbg a WM_LBUTTONUP that I don't want gets queued.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I need to observe the message handling during and after that time, when other posted messages and wm_timers may be getting processed.

Answer (score 1):

not 64 bit but 32 bit 
supply the end address 
( top of stack or return address is what i give @$ra and don't release the mouse
it is not mandatory that you give @$ra but you should be sure that you will reach the end address
eventually without releasing the mouse lsft button)

```
0:000> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  6e57a2ee     0001 (0001)  0:**** COMCTL32!TV_ButtonDown "wt -m comctl32 @$ra"
0:000> g
   17     0 [  0] COMCTL32!TV_ButtonDown
   10     0 [  1]   COMCTL32!GetMessagePosClient
    3     0 [  2]     USER32!GetMessagePos
   18     3 [  1]   COMCTL32!GetMessagePosClient
   17     0 [  2]     USER32!ScreenToClient
   25    20 [  1]   COMCTL32!GetMessagePosClient
   20    45 [  0] COMCTL32!TV_ButtonDown
   22     0 [  1]   COMCTL32!TV_DismissEdit
   14     0 [  2]     USER32!IsWindowVisible
   26    14 [  1]   COMCTL32!TV_DismissEdit
   10     0 [  2]     USER32!GetDlgCtrlID
   33    24 [  1]   COMCTL32!TV_DismissEdit
   10     0 [  2]     USER32!SetWindowLongW
   48    34 [  1]   COMCTL32!TV_DismissEdit
   16     0 [  2]     COMCTL32!TV_InvalidateItem
   40     0 [  3]       COMCTL32!TV_GetItemRect
   24    40 [  2]     COMCTL32!TV_InvalidateItem
    4     0 [  3]       USER32!NtUserRedrawWindow
   27    44 [  2]     COMCTL32!TV_InvalidateItem
   52   105 [  1]   COMCTL32!TV_DismissEdit
    4     0 [  2]     USER32!NtUserShowWindow
   58   109 [  1]   COMCTL32!TV_DismissEdit
   34     0 [  2]     COMCTL32!CCSendNotify
   25     0 [  3]       USER32!GetParent
   40    25 [  2]     COMCTL32!CCSendNotify
   18     0 [  3]       USER32!GetWindow
   44    43 [  2]     COMCTL32!CCSendNotify
   10     0 [  3]       USER32!GetDlgCtrlID
   57    53 [  2]     COMCTL32!CCSendNotify
   24     0 [  3]       USER32!GetWindowThreadProcessId
   60    77 [  2]     COMCTL32!CCSendNotify
    1     0 [  3]       kernel32!GetCurrentProcessIdStub
    1     0 [  3]       kernel32!GetCurrentProcessId
    3     0 [  3]       KERNELBASE!GetCurrentProcessId
   87    82 [  2]     COMCTL32!CCSendNotify
   24     0 [  3]       USER32!SendMessageW
  109   106 [  2]     COMCTL32!CCSendNotify
   16     0 [  3]       COMCTL32!InOutAtoW
  118   122 [  2]     COMCTL32!CCSendNotify
    3     0 [  3]       COMCTL32!__security_check_cookie
  120   125 [  2]     COMCTL32!CCSendNotify
   67   354 [  1]   COMCTL32!TV_DismissEdit
    4     0 [  2]     USER32!NtUserDestroyWindow
   75   358 [  1]   COMCTL32!TV_DismissEdit
    3     0 [  2]     COMCTL32!__security_check_cookie
   77   361 [  1]   COMCTL32!TV_DismissEdit
   27   483 [  0] COMCTL32!TV_ButtonDown
    3     0 [  1]   COMCTL32!__security_check_cookie
   29   486 [  0] COMCTL32!TV_ButtonDown

515 instructions were executed in 514 events (0 from other threads)

Function Name                               Invocations MinInst MaxInst AvgInst
COMCTL32!CCSendNotify                                 1     120     120     120
COMCTL32!GetMessagePosClient                          1      25      25      25
COMCTL32!InOutAtoW                                    1      16      16      16
COMCTL32!TV_ButtonDown                                1      29      29      29
COMCTL32!TV_DismissEdit                               1      77      77      77
COMCTL32!TV_GetItemRect                               1      40      40      40
COMCTL32!TV_InvalidateItem                            1      27      27      27
COMCTL32!__security_check_cookie                      3       3       3       3
KERNELBASE!GetCurrentProcessId                        1       3       3       3
USER32!GetDlgCtrlID                                   2      10      10      10
USER32!GetMessagePos                                  1       3       3       3
USER32!GetParent                                      1      25      25      25
USER32!GetWindow                                      1      18      18      18
USER32!GetWindowThreadProcessId                       1      24      24      24
USER32!IsWindowVisible                                1      14      14      14
USER32!NtUserDestroyWindow                            1       4       4       4
USER32!NtUserRedrawWindow                             1       4       4       4
USER32!NtUserShowWindow                               1       4       4       4
USER32!ScreenToClient                                 1      17      17      17
USER32!SendMessageW                                   1      24      24      24
USER32!SetWindowLongW                                 1      10      10      10
kernel32!GetCurrentProcessId                          1       1       1       1
kernel32!GetCurrentProcessIdStub                      1       1       1       1

0 system calls were executed

eax=00000000 ebx=00000201 ecx=422f0fd7 edx=77a370f4 esi=002d9590 edi=00000200
eip=6e542888 esp=0012fcc4 ebp=0012fd00 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
COMCTL32!TV_WndProc+0x577:
6e542888 e90a060000      jmp     COMCTL32!TV_WndProc+0x5de (6e542e97)
```

Comment: Looks like my initial problem was actually caused by WinDbg Preview. Sorry, I didn't mention I was using that. I used normal WinDbg and it works (sort of).

Comment: Unfortunately It still stops after tracing a bit I get stopped here:
WARNING: This break is not a step/trace completion.
The last command has been cleared to prevent
accidental continuation of this unrelated event.
Check the event, location and thread before resuming.
(16c.3f6c): Single step exception - code 80000004 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatch